# Finding the Median using Reduce-and-Conquer

Tags: java, median

Hello I'm having difficulties with the following problem, I seem to 
1) Not fully understand the *partition* method 
2) I can't to pinpoint the problem with my code.

**Problem Description**: Find the median in an array of three or more integers using reduce-and-conquer recursively. We'll use the convention of considering only part of the array that begins at a given index and ends at another. In this way, a recursive call can work through any part of the array. The initial call will pass in index 0 and the index to the last element.

rAcMedian([2, 1, 3, -2, 8], 0, 4) → 2
rAcMedian([-4, 6, 2], 0, 2) → 2
rAcMedian([4, 2, 48, 1, 50], 0, 4) → 4

Code Give to me:

```
int partition(int[] nums, int begin, int end) {
  int splitPos = begin;
  int pivotValue = nums[begin];
  for(int i=begin+1; i<=end; i++) {
    if(nums[i] > pivotValue) {
      splitPos++;
      swap(nums, i, splitPos);
    }
  }
  swap(nums, begin, splitPos);
  return splitPos;
}

void swap(int[] nums, int pos1, int pos2) {
  int temp = nums[pos1];
  nums[pos1] = nums[pos2];
  nums[pos2] = temp;
}
```

This is my code:

```
public int rAcMedian(int[] nums, int begin, int end) {
  if (begin < end){
    int splitPos = partition(nums, begin, end);

    if (splitPos == end/2) return nums[splitPos];
    if (splitPos > end/2) return nums[rAcMedian(nums, splitPos+1, end)];
    if (splitPos < end/2) return nums[rAcMedian(nums, begin, splitPos-1)];

  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the code I get the following errors:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to merge sort the array and take the middle value(n/2 on even length n/2 + 1 on odd length).

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Answer (score 1):

When you call *partition* on an array, you take the first value in the array as your *pivotValue*. When *partition* is over, all elements left from *pivotValue* are greater than pivotValue, all on the right are smaller or equal.
The integer that is returned is the position that pivotValue ends up. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {4, 3, 1, 7, 5};
    int part = partition(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));   //[5, 7, 4, 3, 1]
    System.out.println(part);   //2
}
```

There are 2 elements greater than the *pivotValue* 4. Because of this, the 4 was shifted 2 places to the right and ends up at index 2, which is also returned at the end.

Note that I made your given functions static so that I can use them.

I guess with the help of these functions you can create your own [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)-algorithm and then, after you sorted the array, just take the middle element. Your teachers propably intended to use it another way though.